# Error with comparing Token (PVU) with busd

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to buy a token with busd but I am getting insufficient balance error, I think it is taking the bnb value instead of taking the busd value. I have busd balance 3.6 and bnb 0.08 enough to pay for the gas. Someone can help me, I think I have to modify the sender_address to take the busd values.

```
sender_address = '0x4B482AF40E773F79DBabb2D3aE9D8EcF1A686db8'

#Obtener el balance de BUSD
contract = web3.toChecksumAddress(0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56)
TokenContract = web3.eth.contract(contract, abi=abi)
balance = TokenContract.functions.balanceOf(sender_address).call()
symbol = TokenContract.functions.symbol().call()
readable = web3.fromWei(balance,'ether')
print("Balance: " + str(readable) + " " + symbol)

#Dirección del contrato del token que queremos comprar
tokenToBuy = web3.toChecksumAddress(input("Enter TokenAddress: "))   #web3.toChecksumAddress("0x31471e0791fcdbe82fbf4c44943255e923f1b794")
spend = web3.toChecksumAddress(0xe9e7CEA3DedcA5984780Bafc599bD69ADd087D56)  #busd contract
 
#Configurar el contrato PancakeSwap
contract = web3.eth.contract(address=panRouterContractAddress, abi=panabi)

nonce = web3.eth.get_transaction_count(sender_address)
 
start = time.time()

pancakeswap2_txn = contract.functions.swapExactETHForTokens(
0, [spend,tokenToBuy],
sender_address,
(int(time.time()) + 10000)
).buildTransaction({
'from': sender_address,
'value': web3.toWei(1,'ether'),#Esta es la cantidad de Token(BUSD) que quieres intercambiar
'gas': 250000,
'gasPrice': web3.toWei('5','gwei'),
'nonce': nonce,
})
    
signed_txn = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(pancakeswap2_txn, private_key=config.private)
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
print(web3.toHex(tx_token))
```

*Error
PS C:\Users\Josdelys\Desktop\Snipercompraventa-main> python prueba.py
True
Balance: 3.683348338171764961 BUSD
Enter TokenAddress: 0x31471e0791fcdbe82fbf4c44943255e923f1b794
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Josdelys\Desktop\Snipercompraventa-main\prueba.py", line 55, in 
tx_token = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
File "C:\Users\Josdelys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\eth.py", line 783, in send_raw_transaction
return self._send_raw_transaction(transaction)
File "C:\Users\Josdelys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\module.py", line 57, in caller
result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
File "C:\Users\Josdelys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
return self.formatted_response(response,
File "C:\Users\Josdelys\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\web3\manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'code': -32000, 'message': 'insufficient funds for gas * price + value'}*